# Android Studio, Intel HAXM cannot find VT-x enabled but enabled in BIOS

Tags: android, virtualization, windows-7-x64, bios, haxm

Unable to install intel HAXM instead of the fact that VT is enabled in BIOS. I am using intel core2 quad q9550 processor and windows 7 over it. My processor does not support hyper-visor.

[image: Error![][1]]

[image: CPU Info]

Comment: I know this is not the answer to the question, but test on a real device instead of AVD. It's much faster and more easy to test and debug!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Instead of installing intelhaxm-android that comes with android studio, try downloading the latest version of haxm from intel:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/14/troubleshooting-intel-haxm

Run that instead and it should install fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU does have VT-x and ND bit so is capable. So
1.If you're using Avast, need to remove and then reinstall HAXM again.  (Or at least disable hardware virtualization under Settings and make sure Hyper-V under Programs list (Windows parts) is not checked. 
2.  (to boot with Hyper-V off…. 
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
3. Make sure ND bit is enabled. bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn