# Android Studio Emulator VT-x not found in bios and intel HAXM not install

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Android Studio Emulator VT-x problem:-

Virtualization not found in bios and intel HAXM not install in my system.

Android Studio emulator not starting due to HAXM VT-X, how can i solve this problem of emulator?

If anybody know, please help me....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio, Intel HAXM cannot find VT-x enabled but enabled in BIOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778938/android-studio-intel-haxm-cannot-find-vt-x-enabled-but-enabled-in-bios)

Comment: Do you know whether your motherboard supports VT? If yes, flash BIOS or ask motherboard vendor about how to enable VT in BIOS.

Comment: Aown Raza Sir, its not a duplicate of that question... I have no option of virtualization in System BIOS, where as in that link he enabled virtualization from BIOS. Please check it

Comment: Yushulx sir, good question. No i think my motherboard not support VT. Because there is no option for Virtualization.