# how to run application in android studio,i try to run but some error is occurring,

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image: image description here]

from where i should downlode AVD

Comment: try using this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Comment: Maybe you can use this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor

Comment: You need to change the BIOS setting to run the app on the AVD..You can also use the Bluestack to run the application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error during installing HAXM, VT-X not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working)

Comment: thank you so much it is really help @RavindraKushwaha,after changing BISO setting my program is running

Comment: @Palak..happy to help u :)

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha,I need to ask one more Question how to add image bundles in layout,do i need to use 2D array in grid view

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha,its really helpfull for people like who are just a beginner in development and no one to help them,can I ask you one more  question,if you don't mind....;)

Comment: @PalakJain , u can ask the question here on SO..Keep in mind , wherever u are posting the question here, than u need to put some effort on it before asking question..Keep happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The error mentioning that your system bios has disabled the VT configured.
So you  have to run the system again and open  bios options then you can enable the  options..for that please share the system and mother board details so can share you further details according to that.

There are so many link for so many type of systems :
here's few ::

-- [Error during installing HAXM, VT-X not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working)

-- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Cv2Hj2PlQE

-- [Android Studio, emulator, HAXM, VT-x not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913121/android-studio-emulator-haxm-vt-x-not-working)

-- [Android Studio, Intel HAXM cannot find VT-x enabled but enabled in BIOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778938/android-studio-intel-haxm-cannot-find-vt-x-enabled-but-enabled-in-bios)

Hope any one will works for you..

Answer (score 0):

Use Real android device for testing application instead of using Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link for enable BIOS it will help you to solved your problem 
[Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor)